# Subclassing numpy scalar types

Tags: python, numpy, subclass, user-defined-types

I'm trying to subclass `numpy.complex64` in order to make use of the way numpy stores the data, (contiguous, alternating real and imaginary part) but use my own `__add__`, `__sub__`, ... routines.

My problem is that when I make a `numpy.ndarray`, setting `dtype=mysubclass`, I get a `numpy.ndarray` with `dtype='numpy.complex64'` in stead, which results in numpy not using my own functions for additions, subtractions and so on.

Example:

```py
import numpy as np
class mysubclass(np.complex64):
    pass

a = mysubclass(1+1j)
A = np.empty(2, dtype=mysubclass)

print type(a)
print repr(A)
```

Output:

```py
<class '__main__.mysubclass'>
array([ -2.07782988e-20 +4.58546896e-41j,  -2.07782988e-20 +4.58546896e-41j], dtype=complex64)'
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance - Soren

Comment: I think a saw a similar question recently, but can't find it right now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NumPy type system is only designed to be extended from C, via the [`PyArray_RegisterDataType`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html#PyArray_RegisterDataType) function.  It *may* be possible to access this functionality from Python using ctypes but I wouldn't recommend it; better to write an extension in C or Cython, or subclass `ndarray` as @seberg describes.

There's a simple example dtype in the NumPy source tree: [newdtype_example/floatint.c](http://projects.scipy.org/numpy/browser/trunk/numpy/doc/newdtype_example/floatint.c?rev=4848).  If you're into Pyrex, [reference.pyx](http://www.pytables.org/svn/pytables/branches/dimension-scales2/tables/reference.pyx) in the pytables source may be worth a look.

Comment: I was hoping to stay out of C, but I guess it's difficult to avoid when doing this kind of stuff.

I'll look at the example and try my luck - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Note that scalars and arrays are quite different in numpy. `np.complex64` (this is 32-bit float, just to note, not double precision). You will not be able to change the array like that, you will need to subclass the array instead and then override its `__add__` and `__sub__`.

If that is all you want to do, it should just work otherwise look at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html since subclassing an array is not that simple.

However if you want to use this type also as a scalar. For example you want to index scalars out, it gets more difficult at least currently. You can get a little further by defining `__array_wrap__` to convert to scalars to your own scalar type for some reduce functions, for indexing to work in all cases it appears to me that you may have define your own `__getitem__` currently.

In all cases with this approach, you still use the complex datatype, and all functions that are not explicitly overridden will still behave the same. @ecatmur mentioned that you can create new datatypes from the C side, if that is really what you want.

Comment: It seems that creating the dtype in C is the better approach. Thanks!