# How to inherit from numpy.float and enforce non-negative numbers

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, oop

I would like to inherit from `numpy.float` to create a `cash` class.

```
class Cash(numpy.float):

    def __init__(self, amount, currency='$'):
        super().__init__()
        self.amount = amount
        self.currency = currency

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Cash({round(self.amount, 2)}{self.currency})"
```

What would be the best strategy to enforce that this class is non-negative during arithmitic? For instance, this test method returns `-2.0`, but I want it to raise a ValueError.

```
def test_sub1(self):
    c1 = Cash(4.00)
    c2 = Cash(6)
    self.assertEqual(2, c1 - c2)
```

Comment: First step would be to override all arithmetic magic functions, e.g. `__sub__ ` or `__add__` and raise the error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subclassing numpy scalar types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729521/subclassing-numpy-scalar-types)